# Subquery two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT ProductID,
       UnitPrice                                               AS SalePrice,
       (SELECT ListPrice
        FROM   Production.Product
        WHERE  Product.ProductID = SalesOrderDetail.ProductID) AS ProductListPrice
FROM   Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

I have a doubt in this query.

The subquery runs while I execute it with the main query. But when I execute the subquery alone it doesn't execute.

It throws an error

> The multi-part identifier "SalesOrderDetail.ProductID" could not be
>   bound.

Can somebody tell em why is this happening?

Comment: Cuz you don't have `SalesOrderDetail` in your sub query alone.

Comment: Look for `correlated sub-query` this is pretty basic stuff in `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

It's because "SalesOrderDetail" is a table on the outer query, you are "passing" it to your subquery.

Also, your query will fail if the subquery is returning more the one value.

A (better) equivalent would be:

```
SELECT ProductID,
       UnitPrice AS SalePrice
       ListPrice AS ProductListPrice
FROM Production.Product
     INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail
         ON Product.ProductID = SalesOrderDetail.ProductID
```

Comment: This won't return him sales rows that don't have a Production.Product row

Comment: Well, doesn't have sense in this situation... you can't sell what you don't have. Changed the LEFT JOIN to an INNER, as it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the main query, it is providing all the values for `Product.ProductID` via `SalesOrderDetail.ProductID`. When you run the subquery on it's own, it has nothing to provide these values.

If you want to run the sub query on it's own then you can, but you'll need to change it slightly to provide your own values. Like this:

```
SELECT ListPrice FROM Production.Product
WHERE Product.ProductID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Where 1,2 and 3 are the IDs of the product list prices that you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have as part of your column list can normally "see" the SalesOrderDetail table in your main query. When you run the query by itself, there is no table called SalesOrderDetail, and so when it tries to find the table to retrieve the ProductId column it cant find it and gives you the error.

Your main query, as written will work if your Production.Product table has only 1 row with the ProductID required - presumably since its an ID you already have this covered using a IDENTITY column or similar. For future queries however you should be aware that if a query in the column list can return more than 1 result, you will get the following:

`"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."`

You can just as easily write your query without the sub-query:

```
SELECT ProductID,
       UnitPrice AS SalePrice,
       Product.ListPrice AS ProductListPrice
FROM   Sales.SalesOrderDetail
INNER JOIN Production.Product ON Product.ProductID = SalesOrderDetail.ProductID
```

You don't need any `LEFT JOIN` or `APPLY` here, as it seems you will always have a product if you have a sales order for it?

If you don't always have a product, you could just replace the `INNER` with a `LEFT` join above.